# WPF improving autoscroll to newly added item in DataGrid VirtualingStackPanel

Tags: wpf, performance, datagrid, virtualization, autoscroll

I have this code to implement an "autoscroll to the newly added Item" behavior in DataGrid with VirtualingStackPanel (Mode = recycling ) :

```
    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(System.Collections.IEnumerable oldValue, System.Collections.IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);

        if (oldValue is INotifyCollectionChanged)
            (oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged -= ItemsCollectionChanged;

        if (!(newValue is INotifyCollectionChanged)) return;

        (newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged += ItemsCollectionChanged;
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        // Dig out and store a reference to our internal ScrollViewer  
        _scrollViewer = RecursiveVisualChildFinder<ScrollViewer>(this) as ScrollViewer;
        _vsp = GetInnerStackPanel(this);
        if (_scrollViewer != null )
        {
            //UpdateLayout();
            _scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
        }
    }

    private void ItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_scrollViewer != null && e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            //UpdateLayout();
            //_needRefresh = true;
            _stopWatch.Start();
            _scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
            _stopWatch.Stop();
            _measures.Add(_stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
```

The problem with this solution is performances : the call "_scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom()" is linear in time to the Item count :  for example: in my test ,i have a factor like 1 ms for 1000 Items, so if i have mor than 1 000 000 items, the autoscroll take more than 1 sec !

How do I get the datagrid (Or any ItemControl with VirtualingStackPanel) to scroll quickly to the last Item ?

Thanks for your Ideas :)

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the overall height and ScrollToVerticalOffset ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same: internally the function "ScrollToBottom()" is implementing with "ScrollToVerticalOffset()"

Comment: I tried also VirtualingStackPanel.BringIndexIntoView(index = Items.Count-1) but it's worse !